# HTML5 translate relative to page

Tags: javascript, css, html, webkit, html5-animation

How can you apply a translate to an element but make it move to a point on the page rather than relative to itself?

For example, in the code below the "card" elements will move 50, 100 relative to their starting position. What I want instead is for it to move to the center of the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.face {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 140;
    width: 80;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
    height: 100;
    width: 80;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin-left: 5px;
     -webkit-transition-property: transform;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
     -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.activated {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) translate(50px, 100px);
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
     -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.card').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("activated");
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="card">
<div class="face front">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/64/Edwin_P_Morrow.jpg/100px-Edwin_P_Morrow.jpg" />
<span>blah!</span>
</div>
<div class="face back">explanation</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<div class="face front">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/64/Edwin_P_Morrow.jpg/100px-Edwin_P_Morrow.jpg" />
<span>blah!</span>
</div>
<div class="face back">explanation</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<div class="face front">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/64/Edwin_P_Morrow.jpg/100px-Edwin_P_Morrow.jpg" />
<span>blah!</span>
</div>
<div class="face back">explanation</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<div class="face front">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/64/Edwin_P_Morrow.jpg/100px-Edwin_P_Morrow.jpg" />
<span>blah!</span>
</div>
<div class="face back">explanation</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with HTML5. It's CSS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be using `translate()` for that. I suppose you could simply calculate the correct values or manipulate the `transform-origin` using JavaScript, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using CSS transforms.

You can animate properties as well, so you could remove the `translate()` from `.activate` and change the transition property for `.card`  to:

```
-webkit-transition-property: all;
```

You can then use "regular" CSS to do the positioning and the transition will do the rest. E.g. add these properties to `.activated`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -40px;
```

There is rather a bit of a problem with that, though. While CSS can smoothly transition the `top`, `left` and `margin` properties nicely, it can't smoothly transition the `position` property, so when a card gets activated it'll jump to the top left first and then move smoothly to the center of the page.

I'm not sure if there's a solution to that other than positioning the original cards absolutely as well.

Also, using the `translate()`, the position of the *other* cards isn't affected when you activate one of them. In my example, though, the activated card is taken out of the flow, so the other cards will move left to fill up the gap (as floating elements do). That might not be what you want either. That wouldn't happen if you absolutely position all of them to start with, though.

Of course, there are plenty of questions in the specs themselves about issues like this considering they're still experimental:

- [CSS 2D Transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/)
- [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)

Comment: since he's using jQuery, in order to prevent the jump to 0,0 he can pull the absolute position and change the appropriate values when he adds the `.activated` class.  Something like `var thisOffset = $(this).offset(); $(this).css({'position':'absolute', 'top':thisOffset.top, 'left':thisOffset.left}).addClass('.activated');`

Comment: I ended up using jquery to clone the element, absolutely position the clone over the original which then has its visibility turned off, and doing the animation on that